# How to hide or show a border

Tags: css

I was finding out what the best method is for the next thing.

I want to give every section a border-bottom, but when there is a section that has followed up by a specific section it should not show the bottom border.

```
    <section></section> <!-- has border-bottom -->
    <section></section> <!-- THIS ONE SHOULD NOT HAVE A BORDER BOTTOM, BECAUSE UNDER THIS SECTION IS A SPECIFIC SECTION WITH A CLASS -->
    <section class="highlight"></section> <!-- has border-bottom -->
    <section></section> <!-- has border-bottom -->
```

Comment: There's no previous sibling selector is CSS yet.

Comment: "Previous" negates the "cascading" in "cascading style sheets".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no previous selector, you could fake a border-bottom by adding a border-top on the sections and simply not include one on both the `section:first-of-type` & .highlight class; also, add a bottom-border to the `:last-of-type` like so:

```
section { border-top: 3px solid #aaa; }
section:first-of-type, .highlight { border-top: none; }
section:last-of-type { border-bottom: 3px solid #aaa; }
.highlight { background: yellow; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/toddicus13/JuCGX/5/)

Edit: Typos & basic clarification.

Comment: looks like this is a nice workaround, I thought of using `:before` to hide the border above like this http://jsfiddle.net/37jE7/7/ but it's obviously a worse workaround.

Comment: This is working, only how can I also remove the bottom line below the highlight section?

Comment: @Caspert try applying `.highlight + section { border-top-color:transparent}`

Comment: Keep in mind there's no lte IE8 support for :first-of-type & :last-of-type. You'll have to use Selectivizr [http://selectivizr.com/] & maybe jQuery Extra Selectors [https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors] depending on your JS library.

Comment: @Caspert strange enough because it works OK here http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/JuCGX/11/

Comment: @Caspert the link I posted does not work if the `highlight` is the last section, we just need to fix it a little here http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/JuCGX/12/

Comment: @kingking It works nice. Thank you. I think I know whats wrong. I had a border bottom instead of top, but this is strange why it is not working if I give the section a border-bottom?. Or does I change something else then?

Comment: @Caspert using `border-top` is a work-around (maybe the only one can help you), but which section did you style the `border-bottom`(instead of `border-top`)?

Comment: @kingking I was trying to make all border tops to bottom. But that didn't work.

Comment: @Caspert of course, it can't work, that's why using `border-top` is a work-around. The `border-top` of an element will look like the  `border-bottom` of the element above, but using `border-top` allows us to select the highlighted section and hide its `border-top`, which means the **fake** `border-bottom` of the section above is hidden. If using `border-bottom`, we need to select the section above from the highlighted section (so that we can hide the **real** `border-bottom`) but doing so is impossible in CSS. That's called **backwards selecting**, while we can only select **forwards** in CSS.

Comment: Simple.. Yes clear. Thank you so much for your solution! @kingking

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a CSS answer for you. Because there is no **previous child** selector in CSS until now which you can use and apply to remove the border from that element.

To check for the next element. You need to use JavaScript. CSS won't check for the elements next to the current element.

You can however use CSS to select a specific child using

```
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  border: 0;
}
```

But remember, you cannot apply a condition in a CSS language. You need JavaScript for that.

Comment: Voted but prefer using `:nth-of-type()`

Comment: @Mr.Alien, I never used that so I didn't know that is a part of CSS api. I have however edited it :)

Comment: Than just search that out, whats the difference and you will get my point :)

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a option with css to call one specific div, so I didn't have to do this the hole time?

Comment: Yes, You can you can use classes or ids to target a specific div. You already know them, don't you?

Comment: Maybe but I can't come on it.. :S So if you can give me one example it would be nice!